# multiple pop-up windows in Jquery Rqin

Tags: jquery, html, popup

I am using query rain to create pop-up windows, but I can't seem to figure out why when I click on the button for the second window to appear, the first pop-up window content appears even though they have different IDs.

Here is the code I am working with:

```
<body>

<!-- button to open the popup -->
  <button class="my_popup_open">Open popup</button>

  <!-- Add content to the popup -->
<div id="my_popup">

    ...First pop-up...

    <!-- Add an optional button to close the popup -->
    <button class="my_popup_close"></button>

</div>


<!-- button to open the popup -->
  <button class="my_popup_open">Open Second popup</button>

  <!-- Add content to the popup -->
<div id="my_popupTwo">

    ...Pop-up NUMBER TWO...

    <!-- Add an optional button to close the popup -->
    <button class="my_popup_close"></button>

</div>


  <!-- Include jQuery -->
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Include jQuery Popup Overlay -->
  <script src="http://vast-engineering.github.io/jquery-popup-overlay/jquery.popupoverlay.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      // Initialize the plugin
      $('#my_popup').popup({
        opacity: 0.7,
        transition: 'all 0.3s'
        });

        // Initialize the plugin
      $('#my_popupTwo').popup({
        opacity: 0.7,
        transition: 'all 0.3s'
        });

    });
  </script>


</body>
```

Any suggestions much appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this plugin doesn't handle multiple popup on same page. The solution would be to do a little hack to display the choosen one popup.

[Link to the website of the plugin](http://vast-engineering.github.io/jquery-popup-overlay/)

Try this:

```
<button onclick="$('#my_popup').popup('show');">Open popup</button>

<button onclick="$('#my_popupTwo').popup('show');">Open Second popup</button>
```

EDIT:

About close button :)

```
<button onclick="$('#my_popup').popup('hide');"></button>

<button onclick="$('#my_popupTwo').popup('hide');"></button>
```

Comment: great idea! works really well except for the close button on the second pop up window. Any ideas of how to do a little hack for that to work?